# differences of n in TCP and UDP?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

This is kind od exam question,
n is equal to?

```
write(sfd,buf,1024) (server)

n = read(cfd,buf,2048) (klient)
```

buf is not important, max size of buff (1024 and 2048)

Comment: sorry but it's really hard to understand your question... What do you want?

Comment: i know, but i mean the differences of n in write and read on udp connection and on tcp connection

Comment: So say so. In your question. And fix the spelling of 'client' while you're at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) return the number of bytes read/written, or -1 on error.

Note, that to be able to invoke `read`/`write` on a UDP socket (or, more generally, on a datagram socket) you have to invoke [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) on it beforehand to specify the peer address.

Comment: `read()` returns zero at end of stream in TCP. There is no end of stream in UDP, but there is an empty datagram instead, which also returns zero.